# How to programmatically change the NSAttributedString of a UITextView without modifying the attributes set on the interface builder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, attributes, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am using the following code to edit the text only, but it is not working:

```
- (void)updateTextViewWithText:(NSString *)newText
{      
    NSDictionary *attributes = [self.textView.attributedText attributesAtIndex:0 effectiveRange:NULL];
    self.textView.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:newText attributes:attributes];
}
```

It is working now. The problem was that on the interface builder the property "Selectable" was not selected for the textView so that was why it returned nil for the attributedText attributes.

Comment: What do you see? Is the text view being updated at all?

Comment: The text is updated but the font size and color from interface builder are lost and reset to defaults.

Comment: The problem was that on the interface builder the property "Selectable" was not selected for the textView so that was why it returned nil for the attributedText attributes. I tried with "Plain" and "Attributed" and it worked for both options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I tried your code sample. It sounds like either your textView IBOutlet is not connected or in Interface Builder you have to change your text from "Plain" to "Attributed".